Appropriate way to handle exception in Java n-tier application
I have three layers in my application Controller, Service and DAO. My controller and service layers are in spring meanwhile DAO layer is in Hibernate 6. My question is what is most appropriate way to handle exception while CRUD operations.
For example if I just log general exception in DAO, I get detailed information in logs only and on frontend I get could not insert record.
try{
} catch(Exception e){
logger("Error in DAO {}", e.getMessage(), e)
}

I have three questions

Should I catch general exception? If yes where it should be caught?
If I catch HibernateException in DAO layer I still can not let user know what caused the exception exactly and if I catch ConstraintViolationException how can I handle grammar exception or exception which occurs when database server goes down etc?
Where should I translate exception? Should I just log and throw exceptions from DAO to Service layer and translate them in Service layer or should I translate exception to appropriate error message in DAO layer?


To summarize mrSoh’s answer:  never catch java.lang.Exception or java.lang.Throwable.  Always throw a new exception, with the caught persistence exception as its cause, so your application doesn’t pretend to work when in fact it did not work.

Dealing with an n-Layer architecture, adhere to the first SOLID Principle, the Single Responsibility Principle.
In your DAO Layer for example, Catch specific exceptions like HibernateException, ConstraintViolationException, etc... Avoid catching generic Exception in the DAO layer as it can mask other potential issues.
In your Service Layer,  Catch more general exceptions and handle or translate them accordingly. The service layer can catch exceptions thrown by the DAO layer and translate them into application-specific exceptions or messages.
Here is a simplified example to get you going with the idea:
DAO:
public void insertRecord(Entity entity) {
    try {
        session.save(entity);
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        logger.error("Constraint violation in DAO: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new CustomConstraintViolationException("Constraint violation occurred while inserting record.");
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        logger.error("Hibernate exception in DAO: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new CustomDatabaseException("Database error occurred while inserting record.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Unexpected exception in DAO: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new CustomGenericException("An unexpected error occurred.");
    }
}

Service
public void addRecord(Entity entity) {
    try {
        dao.insertRecord(entity);
    } catch (CustomConstraintViolationException e) {
        logger.error("Service layer caught constraint violation: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new ServiceException("Cannot insert record due to constraint violation.");
    } catch (CustomDatabaseException e) {
        logger.error("Service layer caught database exception: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new ServiceException("Database error occurred while processing the request.");
    } catch (CustomGenericException e) {
        logger.error("Service layer caught unexpected exception: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new ServiceException("An unexpected error occurred.");
    }
}

Controller
@PostMapping("/add")
public ResponseEntity<String> addRecord(@RequestBody Entity entity) {
    try {
        service.addRecord(entity);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Record added successfully.");
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        logger.error("Controller caught service exception: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Controller caught unexpected exception: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("An unexpected error occurred.");
    }
}

